# How to develop ruzzle game for web

Tags: game-design, web, easeljs

I am creating a game like ruzzle but i am creating for web . Initially my basic task is to display the alphabets in the html5 canvas the letters should fetched from the database randomly in the html5 canvas tiles and when the user create the word just like in ruzzle , the new words add randomly in the html5 canvas .

Should I use easeljs or any other technology . I also want to include multiplayer gaming both friends can simultaneously play the game with each other.

Comment: What's a "ruzzle"? Do you mean a [puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle)? This question is very broad—I think you should try making it and ask a more specific question when you get stuck on something.

Comment: @Anko On which platform I should start developming it i am new to game programming should i use unity or easeljs?

Comment: Whichever is more suitable for your game. If you don't know, try them.